# Invalid row number (-32768) outside allowable range (0..1048575)

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx

I was trying to export a report in to `xlsx` format using Apache POI. Below is the code used for.

```
public static void main(String[]args){
        try{
            XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook();
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");

            XSSFRow rowhead= sheet.createRow((short)0);
            rowhead.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("column1");
            rowhead.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue("column2");
            rowhead.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue("column3");
            rowhead.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue("column4");
            rowhead.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue("column5");
                 System.out.println("im here");
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:...,....);
            Statement st=con.createStatement();         
            System.out.println("im here1");
            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table3 ");
            System.out.println("im here2");         
            int i=1;
            while(rs.next()){
                XSSFRow row= sheet.createRow((short)i);
                row.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(rs.getString("column1"));
                row.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue(rs.getString("column2"));
                row.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue(rs.getString("column3"));
                row.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue(rs.getString("column4"));
                row.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue(rs.getString("column5"));
                i++;
            }

            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(new File("E:/report.xlsx"));
            wb.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
            System.out.println("Your excel file has been generated!");


        } catch ( Exception ex ) {
            System.out.println(ex);

        }
```

The total row count is only 200000. But while processing, I am getting the Invalid row number error.Here is the output.

```
im here
im here1
im here2
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid row number (-32768) outside allowable range (0..1048575)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The highest value that a short (which you're casting to) can represent is 32,767, after which it wraps around to -32768.

[XSSFSheet.createRow](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#createRow%28int%29) takes an `int`, so you don't need to cast your number.

Comment: The error has gone. Now `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` -- I have my `JAVA_OPTS =-Xms64m -Xmx516m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m`

Comment: @tailorBird Increase the amount of memory available then

Comment: Thanks all. We can use `SXSSF` (Streaming Usermodel API) instead.

Answer (score 2):

**The Integer type in VBA is only 16 bits long**. (I kid you not).

As it's a signed type its range is -32768 to +32767. Incrementing 32767 by 1 causes wrap-around to the smallest number: this is what's happening to you.

Use a `Long` type instead: which is 32 bits long.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use long instead of int.

Answer (score 0):

Ehlo, team!

I try copy rows from **List** to **XSSLSheet**
For this I try execute next code:

```
HashMap<String, XSSFRow> listRows = new HashMap<String, XSSFRow>();
List<XSSFRow> rl = new ArrayList<XSSFRow>(listRows.values());
CellCopyPolicy ccp = new CellCopyPolicy();
ccp.setCopyCellValue(true);
ccp.setCopyCellStyle(false);
ccp.setCopyMergedRegions(false);

destSheet.copyRows(rl, 5, ccp)
```

But system responds with the following message:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid row number (-354) outside
>   allowable range (0..1048575)
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow.setRowNum(XSSFRow.java:407)
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.createRow(XSSFSheet.java:739)
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.copyRows(XSSFSheet.java:2897)

In my case resolve of this trouble - add parametr to CellCopyPolicy:

```
ccp.setCondenseRows(true);
```

Code working area:

```
HashMap<String, XSSFRow> listRows = new HashMap<String, XSSFRow>();
List<XSSFRow> rl = new ArrayList<XSSFRow>(listRows.values());
CellCopyPolicy ccp = new CellCopyPolicy();
ccp.setCopyCellValue(true);
ccp.setCopyCellStyle(false);
ccp.setCopyMergedRegions(false); 
ccp.setCondenseRows(true); //look here

destSheet.copyRows(rl, 5, ccp)
```

Best regards & 73 )